# UPDATE: This is now a Swype related issue: Disable the automatic capitalizing of a sentence's first character in an EditText

Tags: android

I'm implementing an EditText that is used to obtain an rtsp URI from the user. Though it's not a huge issue functionally, I would like to disable the default behavior of the on screen keyboard where the state of the caps key is enabled for the first character of every sentence. From what I've gathered, this cannot be done in the XML via `android:inputType` flags.  Any pointers as to how to do this programatically would be helpful.

I'd like to include the code, but the nature of the project prevents me from doing so.  But I can say that nothing fancy is being done here.  The EditText itself has no other input flags in use, and the only IME option in place is the flag to disable the Extract UI in landscape.  The layout is implemented via XML, not programatically, so there are no custom classes or extensions in the mix either.

**EDIT:**  The `android:capitalize` constant inherited from `TextView` isn't working.  I'm specifically targetting 2.2 on a Galaxy Tab, so I don't know if this has something to do with Samsung's OS tweaks, or if it has something to do with the `capitalize` constant being deprecated.

**EDIT 2:**  Swype is the culprit for not allowing the use of the `capitalize` constant.  Does anyone know if there is a way to make Swype play nice without having to inform the end user to disable Swype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the inherited [`android:capitalize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3acapitalize) attribute from TextView. It accepts `none` (no caps, which is what you want), `sentences` (capitalizes the first word of each sentence), `words` (capitalizes the first letter of every word), and `character` (all caps).

Comment: This isn't working either, see my comment on Nick's answer.  Sorry.

Comment: Where is it stated that capitalize is deprecated? I can't seem to find that anywhere. Also, make sure you're not specifying an inputType as well, might be overriding the capitalization setting. You could also try capitalize="none" combined with inputType="textUri" or just "text" and see what results you get.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#capitalize here is the global capitalize constant that the field in TextView refers to where Google indicates that the constant has been deprecated.  I've figured out that the issue is in fact with Swype and not the deprecation.

Comment: Ah I see. Surprising that's not in the TextView docs directly. Anyway, I'm fairly certain there's nothing you can do about Swype, other than possibly popping up a dialog box suggesting they disable auto-capitalize, which isn't really a good solution. You could probably implement a TextWatcher that would convert the first letter to lowercase.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks.

Comment: The 'inputType=textUri' fixed Swype.  For some reason I didn't see that in your comment when I read it the first time and didn't see it in the documentation either.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, code's hard to see in comments sometimes (should've backticked it). Glad it fixed it for you!

Answer (score 2):

Putting this in the XML for the EditText worked to stop Swype 2.17.59.15552.t100 from forcing capitals:

android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"

Answer (score 1):

Since EditText is subclass of TextView, you should be able to use the [TextView:capitalize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_capitalize) configuration to change the capitalization scheme of the view.  It looks like you might only be able to set none in xml.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried this and it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm suspecting that it is related to the `capitalize` constant being deprecated in favor of the `inputType` class. My apologies.

Comment: Are you setting this to be a singleLine entry?

Comment: No.  I also just tried setting `singleLine="true"` and there was no change in the behavior.  I'm starting to suspect that Swype might be the culprit.

**EDIT:** Confirmed that Swype is the culprit.  But I don't want to have to tell customers to disable Swype when this ships.  Any experience with Swype?

Comment: No, but if you want to fix this, you could try overriding the onTextChange method and simply take the string value of the text area and run toLowerCase() on it.  Just test this before hand in an emulator, becuase i'm not positive it won't cause an infinite loop